# tengo un codigo en html y php para enviar imagen a una carpeta en el servidor

Tags: php, html5, servidor

tengo un codigo en html y php para enviar una imagen a una carpeta en el servidor y unos datos que deberian enviarse a un correo electronico y al ejecutar el formulario no hace nada dejo aqui el codigo html y php para que le den un ojo y si pueden ayudarme:

html:

```
<form action="enviararticulo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


            <div class="row g-3">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control bg-dark border-0"
                   id="producto" name="producto"
                    placeholder="Gurdian Name" />
                  <label for="producto">Producto</label>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control bg-dark border-0"
                   id="marca" name="marca"
                    placeholder="Gurdian Email" />
                  <label for="marca">Marca</label>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control bg-dark border-0"
                   id="nombre" name="nombre"
                    placeholder="Child Age" />
                  <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                </div>
              </div>




              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control bg-dark border-0"
                   id="celular" name="celular"
                    placeholder="Child Age" />
                  <label for="celular">Celular</label>
                </div>
              </div>




              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control bg-dark border-0"
                   id="precio" name="precio"
                    placeholder="Child Age" />
                  <label for="precio">Precio</label>
                </div>
              </div>




              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="email" required class="form-control bg-dark border-0"
                   id="correo" name="correo"
                    placeholder="Child Age" />
                  <label for="correo">correo</label>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control bg-dark border-0"
                   id="sector" name="sector"
                    placeholder="Child Age" />
                  <label for="sector">sector</label>
                </div>
              </div>




              <input type='file' name='imagen' accept="image/*" 
              placeholder="carga tu boucher" required>




              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-3" type="submit" name="submit">
                  ENVIAR
                </button>



              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

y este es el php:

```
<?php
  // Recibir los datos del formulario
  $producto = $_POST['producto'];
  $marca = $_POST['marca'];
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $celular = $_POST['celular'];
  $precio = $_POST['precio'];
  $correo = $_POST['correo'];
  $sector = $_POST['sector'];
  $imagen = $_FILES['foto']['name']; // Se corrige el nombre del archivo de imagen
  $imagen_temp = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']; // Se corrige el nombre del archivo de imagen

  // Procesar la imagen y guardarla en el servidor
  move_uploaded_file($imagen_temp, "ciudadcordial/uploads/$imagen");

  // Establecer los encabezados del correo
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $nombre <$correo>\r\n";

  // Crear el cuerpo del mensaje
  $mensaje = "
    <h2>Nuevo artículo enviado</h2>
    <p><strong>Producto:</strong> $producto</p>
    <p><strong>Marca:</strong> $marca</p>
    <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> $nombre</p>
    <p><strong>Celular:</strong> $celular</p>
    <p><strong>Precio:</strong> $precio</p>
    <p><strong>Correo:</strong> $correo</p>
    <p><strong>Sector:</strong> $sector</p>
    <p><strong>Imagen:</strong> 
    <a href='ciudadcordial/uploads/$imagen'>Ver imagen</a></p>";

  // Enviar el correo
  mail("ciudadcordialdeltachira@gmail.com", 
  "Nuevo artículo enviado", $mensaje, $headers);
  
  // Mostrar un mensaje de éxito y redirigir a la página principal
  echo "<script>alert('Articulo Enviado Exitosamente. Pronto será Publicado.')</script>";
  echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='index.html'\",1000)</script>";
?>
```

basicamente lo que quiero recibir es una foto de un producto que se guarde en una carpeta en el servidor. para luego sacar de la carpeta por ftp y que sea publicado en la web y los datos descriptivos del articulo que lleguen al correo electronico.

si alguien me puede ayudar agradecido porque yo veo el codigo todo bien pero no se ejecuta le doy enviar y al correo no llega nada ni a la carpeta se adjunta el archivo de imagen.